# why my reducer keep return undefined as optional?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm using redux and building reducer called **topicReducer** with typescript.

although I've never been typed undefined as state, compiler keep complain about ** undefined **. 
What can I do for not complain type **undefined**?

```js
export type TopicName = 
  'all' 
  | 'etc' 
  | 'ktx' 
  | 'netflix' 
  | 'watcha' 
  | 'share' 
  | 'roommate'
  | 'adobe'


export interface InitialState{
  topic: TopicName
  data: CardData[]; 
}
export const initialState = {} as InitialState;

export interface DispatchAction extends Action {
  payload : Partial<InitialState>;
}


export const topicReducer = (
  state = initialState, action: DispatchAction
) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'all':
    case 'etc':
    case 'netflix':
    case 'adobe':
    case 'watcha':
    case 'roommate':
    case 'newspaper':
    case 'share':
    case 'ktx':
      return {
        topic: action.payload.topic,
        data: action.payload.data 
      }
    default:
      throw new Error(`unknown topic name ${action.type}`); 
  } 
}

export type TopicState = ReturnType<typeof topicReducer>; 



// reducer
export interface RootReducer{
  topic: typeof topicReducer 
}
export const reducerIntegration: RootReducer = {
  topic: topicReducer 
}
export const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducerIntegration);
```

the problem is reducerIntegration throws type complain

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<{ topic: { topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }; }, any>): Reducer<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'RootReducer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject<{ topic: { topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }; }, any>'.
      Types of property 'topic' are incompatible.
        Type '(state: InitialState | undefined, action: DispatchAction) => { topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }, any>'.
          Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
            Type '{ topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'InitialState | undefined'.
              Type '{ topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'InitialState'.
                Types of property 'topic' are incompatible.
                  Type '"all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'TopicName'.
                    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'TopicName'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<{ topic: { topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }; }, AnyAction>): Reducer<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'RootReducer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject<{ topic: { topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }; }, AnyAction>'.
      Types of property 'topic' are incompatible.
        Type '(state: InitialState | undefined, action: DispatchAction) => { topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }, AnyAction>'.
          Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
            Type '{ topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'InitialState | undefined'.
              Type '{ topic: "all" | "etc" | "ktx" | "netflix" | "watcha" | "share" | "roommate" | "adobe" | undefined; data: CardData[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'InitialState'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<any, any>): Reducer<CombinedState<{ [x: string]: any; }>, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'RootReducer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject<any, any>'.
      Index signature is missing in type 'RootReducer'.ts(2769)
```

I want to throw Error in topicReducer if entered action.type is not part of TopicName, also don't want to see **undefined** as a complain.  How can I fix this problem?